# React - Access to an object property which is settled in useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-context

I'm trying to access a property of an object like this one:

```
export const ListingDef = {
  assistant: {
      title: 'a'
  },
  contract: {
      title: 'b'
  },
  child: {
      title: 'c'
  }}
```

I'm using Context and I have a 'listingType' property (empty string) in my state and I define its value in a useEffect hook:

```
const Listing = ({type}) => {

  const {listingType, setListingType} = useContext(ListingContext);
  useEffect(() => {
      setListingType(type);
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
        <h1 className="listing-title">{ListingDef[listingType].title}</h1>
        <ListingTable/>
    </>
)}
```

That way, I can access to `ListingDef[listingType].title`. But I'm facing this issue:

```
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

At first render, `listingType` is equal to empty string so I think I understand why I get this error back.

In other components, I would access to other properties of my object also based on `listingType` value.

It works if I deal with boolean condition, but is there anyway to avoid `if(listingType)...` each time I want to access to my object.

(It works fine if I use `type` directly from the props but I need this value in other components)

Thank you :)

My Context file:

```
const initialState = {
listingType: '',
listingData: [],
loading: true
}

export const ListingContext = createContext(initialState);

export const ListingProvider = ({children}) => {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ListingReducer, initialState);

const setListingType = (type) => {
     dispatch({
        type: SET_LISTING_TYPE,
        payload: type
    })
}

const getListingData = async (listingType) => {
    try {
        const data = await listObjects(listingType);
        dispatch({
            type: GET_LISTING_DATA,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (err) {

    }
}

const contextValue = {
    setListingType,
    getListingData,
    listingType: state.listingType,
    listingData: state.listingData,
    loading: state.loading
}

return (
    <ListingContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        {children}
    </ListingContext.Provider>
)
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're confusing `useContext` and `useState`; the line should be `const listingType = useContext(ListingContext);` What [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) does is allow components further down the tree to access some value; it doesn't provide a setter like `useState` afaik.

Comment: `setListingType` comes from my Context as an action. I have added my Context file

Comment: Ah, right, that makes sense. Maybe this: `{ListingDef[listingType || type].title}`

Comment: It works, but I have for example a `<ListingTable/>` component, which also need the `listingType` value and I don't want to pass down the props `type` manually.  In this `<ListingTable>` component I also have a useEffect hook which fetch data. In this component `listingType` is also equal to empty string at first render. Maybe I should use `useEffect` only in `<Listing>` and not in its nested component ?

Comment: Is `dispatch` invoked after the component is mounted and is `listingType` value updated?

Comment: Yes everything is working fine, the issue occurs only at the first render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am relatively new to redux but i don't see the point of using useEffect when the prop type is already working. Either use a default value or add the 'type' prop to the useEffect second param.

Comment: Indeed, set a default value which not an empty string works fine . Thank you :)